# Expand container div with content set to nowrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, nowrap

I have a `div` that has some content in it, and set to `white-space: nowrap;` When this happens the `div` stays the same size. How can I make it so that the `div` will continue to wrap to the end of the content that now floats off the right of the page?

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.parent p {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
  <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `.parent{display:inline-block;}` If you want the borders to go all the way to the right of the content.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent p {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
  <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, using overflow: scroll might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you need the content inside your `div` after the `nowrap` text needs to wrap, you could try setting a `display: block` to the first that comes after (or add an element to do this).

A `<br>` tag can also break a `nowrap`

But if this is your intention, it might cause less problems if you set only your piece of text to nowrap, instead of the whole div.